# Access - Linking data in rows to Data in Column

Tags: ms-access

I need to link rows of one table to pull data based on columns of another table. I am attaching the picture that shows the two tables and the desired result. I would really appreciate any help with this. If it can't be done then any workaround will be appreciated.

[image: Access Tables and desired result]

Comment: Hi, @KDARA, welcome to Stackoverflow. To improve your chances of getting an answer i suggest that you take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good question and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will help you get the help you seek much faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use UNION query to rearrange data in Table2 into normalized structure it should be in the first place. There is no query designer or wizard for UNION, must type or copy/paste in SQLView of query builder.

```
SELECT Site, "Infant" AS Category, [Capacity Infant] AS Capacity FROM Table2
UNION SELECT Site, "Toddler", [Capacity Toddler] FROM Table2
UNION SELECT Site, "Preschool", [Capacity Preschool] FROM Table2;
```

Another approach:

```
SELECT Site, Category, DLookUp("[" & "Capacity " & [Category] & "]","Table2","Site='" & [Site] & "'") AS Capacity
FROM Table1;
```

Either can perform slowly with very large dataset, not sure which would be slower.

Comment: Thanks a lot for guiding me I was able to achieve the result using a Union Query   Site_Data is the name of the table, I didn't need to use the second table as it assigned the Infant, Toddler and Preschool Category to each Site Name " SELECT Site_Data.[Site Name], "Infant" As Category, Site_Data.[Operating Capacity Infant] 
FROM Site_Data;

UNION SELECT Site_Data.[Site Name], "Toddler" As Category, Site_Data.[Operating Capacity Toddler]
FROM Site_Data;

UNION SELECT Site_Data.[Site Name], "PreSchool" As Category, Site_Data.[Operating Capacity Pre School]
FROM Site_Data;

Comment: Glad it helped. Might want to mark the answer as accepted. And upvote is always appreciated.